# How to mock a function in the middle of a pipeline without breaking the pipeline?

Tags: elixir

I made this code for an API client:

```
create_request
|> emit
```

In production `emit()` uses the http client (`httpoison`) specified in the config with `Application.get_env(…)`. In the test environment, the http client is not `httpoison` but a module I made that simply does:

```
def request({method, url, body, headers}) do
  send(self(), {method, url, body, headers})
end
```

then my test:

```
test "Emits the request via the http client specified in the environment config" do
  MyClient.emit({:get, "http://google.com", nil, nil})
  assert_received({:get, "http://google.com, nil, nil})
end
```

This test passes.

Now I want to parse the response. So I added a function to the pipeline:

```
create_request
|> emit
|> parse_response
```

Now my test doesn't pass anymore. The input of `parse_response` should be a HTTPoison.Response. In production the pipeline works, but in my tests because of the fake http client that simply `send` the input to `self()` it doesn’t output a value that is compliant with the type of input expected by `process_response`

What are my options ?

1. add a clause to `parse_response` in the production code so it handles that special case (which only happens in tests). Not a big fan of changing production code for the sake of testability
2. similar to 1) but using protocols ?
3. the option 3

Comment: If you depend on `HTTPoison.Reponse`s in the production code, then that seems to be your "interface" which means that's what you'll want to return in your test implementation of an HTTP client. Otherwise, you'll probably want to change the return value of both your test as well as production HTTP client responses. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes that makes sense. So I can either 1) return a fake HTTPoison.Response value after the `send` trick or 2) decouple the response processing code from HTTPoison.Response.

Comment: yes, that's what I meant.